# How to mock a function that runs on controller initialization?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

Controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.firstFn = function() {
        console.log('firstFn called');
        $scope.test1 = 2;
    };

    $scope.secondFn = function() {
        console.log('secondFn called');
        $scope.test2 = 3;
    };

    (function constructor() {
        console.log('Controller init.');
        $scope.test1 = 1;
        $scope.test2 = 2;
        $scope.firstFn();
    })();
};
```

Is it possible to write a unit test for the function called "secondFn" without the "firstFn" being executed ?
Is it possible to mock it or something ?

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
ctrl = $controller('myCtrl', {$scope: scope});
// Mock firstFn ?
scope.secondFn();
// assert $scope.test1 = 1
// assert $scope.test2 = 3
```

Comment: Are you using any testing framework, Jasmine perhaps?

Comment: Yep, I'm using Jasmine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to:

1. Create a mocked version of `firstFn` on `$scope` before creating the controller
2. Prevent the controller from replacing the mock

Unless you are testing for old browsers like IE8, you can accomplish this by using Jasmine´s `createSpy` together with the ECMAScript 5 method `Object.defineProperty()`.

*Note that the following examples are using Jasmine 2.0.*

Create the mock:

```
firstFnMock = jasmine.createSpy('firstFn').and.callFake(function() {
  console.log('firstFnMock called');
});
```

Use `defineProperty` to create a property on `$scope` called `firstFn` and set its value to the mocked function:

```
Object.defineProperty($scope, "firstFn", {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: firstFnMock
});
```

It's important that `writable` is set to `false` as it will prevent the controller from replacing the mock.

Use the prepared `$scope` when creating the controller like normally (setting up a function that creates the controller in this example):

```
createController = function() {
  return _$controller_('MyController', {
    $scope: $scope
  });
};
```

Spec example:

```
it('Spec', function() {

  createController();

  expect(firstFnMock).toHaveBeenCalled();

  $scope.secondFn();

  expect($scope.test1).toBe(1);
  expect($scope.test2).toBe(3);
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/rJuixdHx70SvMcLhGoBz?p=preview

Comment: Wow thanks ! I had lost hope.
It works flawlessly. Exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Just spy on `firstFn`. By default any calls to a spied on function will be to the Jasmine spy object, not to the actual function.

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
ctrl = $controller('myCtrl', {$scope: scope});

spyOn(scope, 'firstFn');
scope.secondFn();
// assert $scope.test1 = 1
// assert $scope.test2 = 3
```

For more control over the behaviour of spies, see http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

Comment: This does not work since the function is executed as soon as the controller is created.

Comment: if the function is private to the controller, and it executes as soon as the controller is created, you're out of luck. Abstract it to a service, then spy on it before creating the controller.